# ERROR: Error installing XSpear-1.4.1.gem: rubyzip requires Ruby version >= 2.4

Tags: ruby, rubygems, failed-installation

I am trying to install XSpear 1.4.1 and I have **ruby version 2.7.1 32-bit** as seen by running the `ruby -v` command:

```
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [i686-linux]
```

But still on running the command `sudo gem install XSpear-1.4.1.gem` in the XSpear directory, I get an error message saying:

```
ERROR:  Error installing XSpear-1.4.1.gem:
        rubyzip requires Ruby version >= 2.4.
```

Why is this happening? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you install Ruby? What if you try without `sudo`? Are you able to use a Ruby manager like RVM or rbenv to install Ruby, and if so are you able to complete the installation using that version of Ruby without `sudo`?

Comment: I had installed it using rbenv. I was able to use it and the installation completed just fine I followed the tutorial on this website - https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/18.04#ruby-rbenv for installing _only_ ruby and not rails. I followed the tutorial for installing ruby with rbenv.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so... After further investigation I got to know that I had Ruby 1.3.0 pre-installed in my computer and I had installed Ruby 2.7.1 over it. I don't know why but during the installation process of Ruby 2.7.1, I wasn't shown any error or warning saying that ruby was already installed (strange). So I guess the computer took Ruby 2.3.0 as the default Ruby version while Ruby displayed the newer version as its default.

I had to remove rbenv, Ruby 2.3.0 and 2.7.1 completely and then reinstall rbenv and  Ruby 2.7.1 and then I could install XSpear.

I don't know if it is a bug or just my foolishness but I'm happy this got solved.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your system most likely came with Ruby preinstalled, because most Linux distros do. How did you install 2.7? Did you use a package manager like apt-get or did you install rbenv and then install 2.7? Because if you installed rbenv and then 2.7 but were still using 2.3 then most likely you did not install rbenv properly. (or failed to reshim) Your reinstall-everything procedure was the right way to go, though, so I'm glad you got it working.